# Implementing Interface anonymously in Kotlin results in "has no constructors" error

Tags: constructor, interface, compiler-errors, kotlin, anonymous-class

I'm trying to use a SurfaceView in Android to hold a Camera preview. The documentation tells me that I need to call startPreview in the surfaceCreated callback for the surface holder. I'm trying to set the callback like so

```
this.surface!!.holder!!.addCallback(SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, 
                       width: Int, height: Int) {

    }

    fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {

    }

    fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {

    }
})
```

However, I get the error:

> SurfaceHolder.Callback has no constructors.

I'm confused why this doesn't work when something like this does:

```
Thread(Runnable() {
    fun run() {
        ...        
    }
})
```

Comment: Your second case is wrong as well, you are not actually overriding the `run()` method in Runnable but passing in a lambda that contains a nested `run()` function that is never called.  Both examples are invalid.

Comment: Also for the run example for Runnable, you don't need to specify the interface either and can just use SAM conversion and pass in a lambda `Thread { ... }`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create an object of an *anonymous subclass* you need to use the [`object:` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
this.surface!!.holder!!.addCallback(object: SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, 
                                width: Int, height: Int) {
        ...        
    }

    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        ...
    }

    override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
        ... 
    }
})
```

and don't forget to use the `override` keyword *per* overridden method as well ;)

Comment: Please add a note about using an `object` expression as well, which was also part of your fix.  And link to documentation https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: @JaysonMinard Yeah, I forgot to mention that error as well... good catch ;)

Comment: If `SurfaceHolder.Callback` is interface, then no `()` after.

Comment: Cheers for this, hunted for awhile. shame you can't lamda these though